# Twitter bootstrap javascript popovers not working

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I've looked around and haven't been able to find anyone with an issue quite like mine.

I've also had a few people inspect my javascript/html for obvious bugs, and have squashed a few of them.

I'm trying to implement a simple javascript popover using twitter bootstrap, as shown 
[here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popover).

As far as I can tell, my code ([here](http://gmc.phantomcraft.net/proto1/)) for a button with a popover is identical to their example code (excluding the content itself), and yet it does nothing.

The button that says "Creative" on my page should have a popover similar to twitter bootstrap's example "Hover for popover" demo button.

Edit: The link to my code no longer shows the problem I was having. However, the issue was that I included the javascript source in the header as type="javascript" instead of type="text/javascript".

Comment: This question is not useful because the link to the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modify the code of the page L138-L146:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[rel=popover]")
        .popover({
            offset: 10
        })
        .click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
        })
});
```

**UPDATE**

O.o

The type of script tag is `text/javascript`. It's like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: herp derp. Thanks a ton. I knew it was something simple like that.